# Combining results in two tables

Tags: sql-server

There are `two tables (Table1 and Table2)` with identical columns.

```
Customerno, amount
```

There is a third table `Customers` with columns:

```
Customerno, customername
```

Currently, the following two queries are run and the combined result is derived using Excel (vlookup etc)

```
Select a.customerno, b.customername, sum(a.amount) 
FROM Table1 a join customers b on a.Customerno = b.Customerno
group by a.customerno, b.customername


Select a.customerno, b.customername, sum(a.amount) 
FROM Table2 a join customers b on a.Customerno = b.Customerno
group by a.customerno, b.customername
```

Would would be the correct way of combining the two queries into one to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a.customerno, b.customername, sum(a.amount) 
FROM 
( 
   SELECT Customerno, amount FROM Table1
   UNION ALL -- use this keep duplicates ie amounts from both tables
   -- UNION -- will discard duplicates 
   SELECT Customerno, amount FROM Table2
) a 
join customers b on a.Customerno = b.Customerno
group by a.customerno, b.customername
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) statement for this. Here is the simplest way to union these two and you can work your way from here.

```
select *
from
(

Select a.customerno, b.customername, sum(a.amount) 
FROM Table1 a join customers b on a.Customerno = b.Customerno
group by a.customerno, b.customername

union -- or union all if you want to keep the duplicates

Select a.customerno, b.customername, sum(a.amount) 
FROM Table2 a join customers b on a.Customerno = b.Customerno
group by a.customerno, b.customername
) P
```